# Beamer - change order of first page elements

Tags: beamer, titles

I would like to use the Warsaw theme for a beamer presentation.

With this theme you have the first page elements (the ones I need) in the following order:

- \title
- \author
- \insititute
- \titlegraphic

while I need the element ordered as:

- \institute
- \titlegraphic
- \title
- \author

Is it possible to obtain this order without rewriting from scratch the Warsaw template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just take the elements from the title page an arrange them to your needs

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title{Very interesting science}
\author{A.\,Einstein}
\date{31. April 1592}
\institute{My Institut}


\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
     \vfill
     \centering

     \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]{institute}
        \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
     \end{beamercolorbox}

     {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}

     \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]{title}
        \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
        \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
        \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
     \end{beamercolorbox}%

     \vskip1em\par

     \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]{author}
        \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
     \end{beamercolorbox}

     \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true]{date}
        \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
     \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]